# CGAL How to use global indices on vertices in dDimensional Triangulation?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, triangulation, cgal, indices

#### The Problem

Using CGAL, I am creating a random point cloud in d-Dimensional space like so:

```
#include <CGAL/Cartesian_d.h>
#include <CGAL/point_generators_d.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_d.h>
#include <CGAL/basic.h>

typedef CGAL::Cartesian_d<double> K;    //Kernel
typedef CGAL::Point_d<K> Point;
typedef std::vector<Point> PointSet;

typedef CGAL::Delaunay_d<K> Delaunayd;
typedef Delaunayd::Simplex_handle S_handle;
typedef Delaunayd::Simplex_iterator S_iterator;
typedef Delaunayd::Vertex_handle V_handle;
typedef Delaunayd::Vertex_iterator V_iterator;

int main()
{
    int mDim = 3;    // will be higher, I use it now for simplicity
    int mNum = 10;
    PointSet mPs;
    CGAL::Random_points_in_cube_d<Point> rpg(d, range);

    for(int i = 0; i < mNum; ++i)
    {
        mPs.push_back(*rpg);
        ++rpg;
    }
...
```

Then I'm using the **dD Convex Hulls and Delaunay Triangulations** package to compute a Delaunay triangulation of that point cloud in d-Dimensions:

```
...

Delaunayd * mT = new Delaunayd(mDim);

PointSet::iterator pt_it = mPs.begin();
PointSet::iterator pt_it_end = mPs.end();
for (; pt_it != pt_it_end; ++pt_it)
{
    V_handle v = mT->insert(*pt_it);
}
...
```

Then I would like to write the triangulation to a *.txt* file in a format like this:

```
d        //number of dimensions
nv ns        // nv - number of vertices(points), ns - number of simplices
// followed by nv lines
coord_0_1  coord_0_2  coord_0_3  ... coord_0_d
...
coord_nv_1 coord_nv_2 coord_nv_3 ... coord_nv_d
//followed by ns lines
v1 v2 v3 ... vd+1
...
v1 v2 v3 ... vd+1
```

Where *v1, ...,  vd+1* are the global indices of the vertices in one simplex. Like it is described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850354/cgal-retrieve-vertex-index-after-delaunay-triangulation).

Now, for 2D and 3D, there are the `CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2` and `CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3` classes which can be used to add any additional info to a vertex. Like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850354/cgal-retrieve-vertex-index-after-delaunay-triangulation)(stackoverflow question).

However, I could not find a clear explanation how to do the same in d-Dimensions.

#### The Search

Searching Google gave me the following results:

- A Master's [thesis](http://etd.nd.edu/ETD-db/theses/available/etd-04102006-141513/unrestricted/LammersfeldJE042006T.pdf) *Implementing four-dimensional triangulations in CGAL*. Here, a user defined simple geometric kernel is implemented, which provides the necessary objects for working in R^4 (`Point_4`, `Orientation_4` etc.). An implementation of a class `Triangulation_vertex_base_4` is mentioned, but I couldn't find the code to see how it's done.
- A [paragraph](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#Section_2D_Triangulations_Flexibility) in the CGAL manual mentioning the flexibility of the design of the `Vertex` and `Face` classes used in 2D and 3D triangulations. There is an example there of extending the `Vertex Base` class with custom data, but if I understood correctly it only works with the already defined `Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info` for 2D and 3D.

#### The Tried Solutions

- I tried modifying the following classes:

  - `Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3.h`
  - `Triangulation_vertex_base_3.h`
  - `Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3.h`
  - `Dummy_tds_3.h`
    Basically, replacing the `3` with `d` but I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing. Then there is the `Triangulation_data_structure_3.h`which looks pretty challenging and I wouldn't go down the road of modifying it for d-Dimensions. There must be an easier way?
- I tried a simple solution of looking up the point for each vertex in the point cloud container that I created in the beginning. The idea is to look at the distance from the point given by the vertex (`Vertex_handle::point()`) to all of the points in the `std::vector<Point>` container and choose the index of the closest point in that container. Here is some code:

  ```
  ...
  int ns = T->all_simplices().size();
  vertIndices [ns][mDim + 1];  // number of simplices and d+1 vertices per simplex
  S_iterator s_it = mT->simplices_begin();
  S_iterator s_it_end = mT->simplices_end();
  int currSimp = 0;
  int numVert = mDim + 1; // number of vertices per simplex
  for (; s_it != s_it_end; ++s_it)
  {
      for(int i = 0; i < numVert; ++i)
      {
          V_handle vh = mT->vertex_of_simplex(s_it, i);
          int idx = findIndexOf(vh, mPs);
          vertIndices[currSimp][i] = idx;
      }
      currSimp++;
  }
  ...
  int findIndexOf(V_handle vh, PointSet mPs)
  {
      Point pt = vh->point();
      int idx = -1;
      int count = 0;
      PointSet::iterator pt_it = mPs.begin();
      PointSet::iterator pt_it_end = mPs.end();
      for (; pt_it != pt_it_end; ++pt_it)
      {
          Point opt = *pt_it;
          K::Vector_d v = pt - opt;         // The problem is here!
          double dst = v.squared_length();
          if (dst < 0.01)
          {
              idx = count;
          }
          count++;
      }
      return idx;
  }
  ```

The problem is that when I try to create that vector, in order to calculate the distance, CGAL throws an unhandled exception (Assertion_exception). I am guessing that this occurs when the two points (from the vhandle and the point cloud) are actually the same. But I might be wrong. Anyways, I can't compute the distance, and Google hasn't been of any help for this either. (I have also tried with creating a `squared_distance_d_object()` but it does the same thing).

#### The Question

Is there an easy way to plug additional information to vertices in d-Dimensional triangulations in CGAL?

Is there another way to get the global indices of the vertices?

What am I doing wrong with the euclidean distance?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

#### Edit 1

I solved the problem for the euclidean distance approach. The point that I was getting with `Point pt = vh->point()` was not compatible with the Cartesian_d::Point_d class. This created problems when creating the vector. I solved the problem with using `Delaunay_d::point_at_simplex(si, i)` method, which I somehow overlooked before.
Now the search for the indices works fine.

It would be nice, however, to find out how to add data to the vertices in d-dimensions.